# SBT sub/build.sbt import dependency of root/build.sbt for task

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a task where I want to access an external package (to do reflection to find all the classes that extend a specific trait of that package)

The package is defined in my parent project along all other dependencies that are set for all subprojects.

Like so:

root/build.sbt:

```
val scalaCss = "com.github.japgolly.scalacss" %% "core" % "0.5.1"

lazy val subproject = (project in file("subproject"))
...
.settings(
...
, libraryDependencies += scalaCss)
```

subproject/build.sbt

```
lazy val myAwesomeTask = TaskKey[Unit]("myAwesomeTask")

myAwesomeTask := {
    import scalaCss.Defaults._
    val standalones = typeOf[scalacss.internal.mutable.StyleSheet.Standalone.Standalone]
  }
```

Now `css.Defaults._` cannot be resolved

How can I change that, so it becomes available in the task?

I want the specific tasks to be specified in the subproject's `build.sbt` but NOT put any dependencies there.

As the subproject itself is already defined in `root/build.sbt` I see no way to specify another dependency on it here. Can I somehow import the `root/build.sbt` to my `subproject/build.sbt`?

Comment: Did my suggestion help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it'll work , but you can try putting common settings in a separate def file and then try this ( from both build files) :

`val sub = Project( id = "sub" , base = file(".")).addSbtFiles("<path/to/common.sbt>")`